# Read csv and retain index names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe that needs to be kept in the structure below.

```
pd.read_csv(filepath, header=[0,1])
  One             two           three      four    
  country        date           apple     banana
0 UK             2015-01-01       0         4
1 US             2020-01-03      10         5
```

How could I keep the first 2 rows and 2 columns to be the index and keep the names?

```
pd.read_csv(filepath, header=[0,1], index_col=[0,1])

       One            three   four       
      country        apple    banana
UK   2015-01-01         0        4
US   2020-01-03        10        5
```

Expected Output is the first 2 rows and first 2 columns to be the index with the proper names

```
One             two           three      four    
country        date           apple     banana
UK             2015-01-01         0         4
US             2020-01-03        10         5
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. the most similar dataframe will be:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=[0,1])
df.set_index(df.columns[0])

                two         three   four
                date        apple   banana
(One, country)          
UK              2015-01-01  0       4
US              2020-01-03  10      5
```